# autocomplete filterChange not firing

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

have an issue with filterChange not firing,
all the other events (which I currently don't need ) work, the only one not firing is the filterChenage.

I use the most basic setup with an autocomlete which currently has only [data] which works perfectly, and (filterChange) which does not.

any help is appreciated
BTW using latest version of all npm packages as of yesterday.

Comment: Seems to work in their official demos - http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/filtering/
Did you enable [filterable]="true" option?

Answer (score 2):

OK

after more digging, found the problem:
I was missing the [filterable]="true" attribute.